# could not call wp_email function twice

Tags: email

I need to call wp_email twice as below, first one is called without issues, however second is not called. it would be great if you could suggest any ideas to resolve the issues.

wp_email(args) – this is for sending emails to the admin or organization
wp_email(args) – this is for sending acknowledgement. But this is failing

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using? We'll need more detail to help.

Comment: The correct function is `wp_mail()`. No ‘e’.